# How to destructure a tuple to multiple tuple in scala

Tags: scala

I have a file containing a line

```
4 3 2
5 6 7
9 8 2
```

I am splitting the line by tab and then want to break the content into 2 pieces

What is the way to convert each line of input to 2 seperate tuple as following-

```
(4 3 2) = (4 1 2) & (3 1 2)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Why did you remove the answer from it?

Comment: it doesn't seem like working

Comment: What problem are you having with it?

Comment: I was getting compile time error but the solution provided below sorted that out

Comment: Next time, if you have a compilation error, ask a question like "how to fix such-and-such compilation error, that I am getting from such-and-such code, that I have written for such-and-such purpose?`. Not "how to do blah?". Be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that:

- each tab-separated line consists of three elements
- elements within each line are separated with exactly one space character
- each line needs to be converted to a tuple of tuples

In case I got any of these wrong (e.g. there can be more than 3 elements in each row or you need different structures than tuples) it can be easily adapted.

```
val file = "4 3 2\t5 6 7\t9 8 2"

val lines = file.split("\t").map(line => line.split(" ").toList)

val newLines = lines.map({
  case a :: b :: c :: Nil => ((a, "1", c), (b, "1", c))
})

newLines.map(println)

//  ((4, 1, 2), (3, 1, 2))
//  ((5, 1, 7), (6, 1, 7))
//  ((9, 1, 2), (8, 1, 2))
```

EDIT:

This answer was based on the logic that you wrote initially in your question and which said that you want this kind of map: `((a b c) => (a 1 c) (b 1 c))`. I can see now that you removed that part so I'm not sure if the logic in my solution is right, but now that you have the basic skeleton you can modify as you need.

Comment: The output above is inside tuple , can I get each output separately like (4,1,2),(3,1,2),(5,1,7),(6,1,7) ?

Comment: got it , I should flatten the list to get the needful, thanks anyway